# Increase counter by 1 for each unique group of values

Tags: r

I want to create a continually increasing counter for each group, where each group is a unique combination of person and day.

This is what the data looks like:

```
> df
  person      date
1      0    monday
2      0   tuesday
3      1    monday
4      1    monday
5      1   tuesday
6      2    monday
7      2    monday
8      2   tuesday
9      2 wednesday
```

Thus, I want to add a new variable starts at 1, and adds for for each new combination of person and day.

```
> df
  person      date counter
1      0    monday       1
2      0   tuesday       2
3      1    monday       3
4      1    monday       3
5      1   tuesday       4
6      2    monday       5
7      2    monday       5
8      2   tuesday       6
9      2 wednesday       7
```

I hope that the data is clear enough. The counter continues until it reaches the end of the data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rleid` from the devel version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)#v.9.5+
 setDT(df)[, counter:= rleid(date)][]
 #    person      date counter
 # 1:      0    monday       1
 # 2:      0   tuesday       2
 # 3:      1    monday       3
 # 4:      1    monday       3
 # 5:      1   tuesday       4
 # 6:      2    monday       5
 # 7:      2    monday       5
 # 8:      2   tuesday       6
 # 9:      2 wednesday       7
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
   mutate(counter= cumsum(date!=lag(date, default=FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The dplyr solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
df1 <- data.frame(unique(df), counter= 1:nrow(unique(df)))
merge(df, df1)
```

Output:

```
  person      date counter
1      0    monday       1
2      0   tuesday       2
3      1    monday       3
4      1    monday       3
5      1   tuesday       4
6      2    monday       5
7      2    monday       5
8      2   tuesday       6
9      2 wednesday       7
```